# How can I get the json string value from a Push Notification?

Tags: ios, json, swift

I need to store the last alert `json` `string` value coming from a Push Notification.

Using `"aps: \(userInfo["aps"]!)"` returns the whole `json`:

```
aps: {
    alert = "last alert message";
}
```

but I only need `"last alert message"`.

This is my code:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
    // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.

    dUserInfo = userInfo
    print("aps: \(userInfo["aps"]!)")

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(dUserInfo, forKey: "last_push")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()     
}
```

How can I get the message properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
if let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? [String: AnyObject] {
            if let alert = aps["alert"] as? String {
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(alert, forKey: "last_push")
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. Is this the best way to get information from json objects?

Comment: I always do this way. But there is many ways to do this and one of them is you can use `swiftyJSON` lib for this.

Comment: Happy to help you..:)

Comment: I'll be taking a look into it